# Black screen with blinking screen and OS not found

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios

I re-installed windows on my Acer 7730z machine and after restarting i see a black screen with a blinking cursor and then after some time i get a message 'operating system not found'. I tried to reinstall windows again, but in vain. The cd didnt boot and i checked in BIOS harddrive is detected and CD ROM was set to as first in boot. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/78836/working-hard-drive-but-operating-system-not-found-how-to-make-visible-to-bio?rq=1 ?

Comment: @bearbin I hope not, in the old post the author is able to install xp and linux, but in my case i am unable to do so and any windows boot cd i load doesnt load upon startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the specs for your laptop, it maybe possible that it has two hard drives.[Acer 7730z specs](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/Aspire7730Z/Aspire7730Zsp2.shtml).

Please check bios, boot sequence screen and tab to a "blank" (or either of the drives for that matter) device option. Hit enter and see if you have a device option (hard drive) that has not been assigned in the boot sequence. If so, swap it to the second boot item and save. It is possible that windows is loaded on the "second" drive but not in the boot sequence. And/Or your hard drive is failing.

Comment: After spending a day with a day with my laptop found that the hard-disk died, but i dont know why the bios was still able to detect it.

Comment: As long as the drive spins up, bios will most likely detect it. If the controller board in the hard drive failed or no power went to the hard drive, or a problem with the sata connection then bios would tell you there is no drive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try resetting your CMOS battery, that helped me once before when a "OS not found" error happened after a failed windows install.